# Springboot and Kafka (Docker) communication via SSL results in Cancelled in-flight API_VERSIONS request

Tags: java, spring-boot, docker, ssl, apache-kafka

I do have a very simple Springboot App with a even simpler Kafka Producer and Client, that I try to connect to a Docker Kafka Broker via SSL. Unfortunately I am unable to get it to work. First of all my configuration looks like this:

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3.1'

services:

  zookeeper:
    image: wurstmeister/zookeeper
    environment:
      ZOOKEEPER_CLIENT_PORT: 2181

  broker:
    image: wurstmeister/kafka
    ports:
      - 9092:9092
      - 9093:9093
    volumes:
      - ./security:/etc/kafka/secrets
    environment:
      KAFKA_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://broker:29092,PLAINTEXT_HOST://localhost:9092,TLS://broker:29093,TLS_HOST://localhost:9093
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://broker:29092,PLAINTEXT_HOST://localhost:9092,TLS://broker:29093,TLS_HOST://localhost:9093
      KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: PLAINTEXT:PLAINTEXT,PLAINTEXT_HOST:PLAINTEXT,TLS:SSL,TLS_HOST:SSL
      KAFKA_INTER_BROKER_LISTENER_NAME: TLS
      KAFKA_OFFSETS_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      KAFKA_TRANSACTION_STATE_LOG_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      KAFKA_AUTO_CREATE_TOPICS_ENABLE: 'false'
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zookeeper:2181
      KAFKA_SSL_KEYSTORE_LOCATION: /etc/kafka/secrets/broker-keypair.pem
      KAFKA_SSL_KEY_PASSWORD: password
      KAFKA_SSL_KEYSTORE_TYPE: PEM
      KAFKA_SSL_TRUSTSTORE_LOCATION: /etc/kafka/secrets/root.crt
      KAFKA_SSL_TRUSTSTORE_TYPE: PEM
      KAFKA_SSL_ENDPOINT_IDENTIFICATION_ALGORITHM: " "
      KAFKA_SSL_CLIENT_AUTH: "required"
      KAFKA_ALLOW_EVERYONE_IF_NO_ACL_FOUND: 'true'
```

KafkaComsumerConfig.java

```
@EnableKafka
@Configuration
public class KafkaConsumerConfig {

    @Value(value = "${spring.kafka.properties.bootstrap.servers}")
    private String bootstrapAddress;

    @Bean
    public ConsumerFactory<String, String> consumerFactory() {
        final Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, bootstrapAddress);
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, "sales.quotation.quotation.receiver");
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);

        props.put(
                SslConfigs.SSL_KEYSTORE_LOCATION_CONFIG,
                "path\\to\\consumer.keystore.jks");
        props.put(SslConfigs.SSL_KEYSTORE_PASSWORD_CONFIG, "password");
        props.put(SslConfigs.SSL_KEY_PASSWORD_CONFIG, "password");
        props.put(
                SslConfigs.SSL_TRUSTSTORE_LOCATION_CONFIG,
                "path\\to\\truststore.jks");
        props.put(SslConfigs.SSL_TRUSTSTORE_PASSWORD_CONFIG, "password");

        return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(props);
    }

    @Bean
    public ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, String> kafkaListenerContainerFactory() {
        final ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, String> factory = new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
        factory.setConsumerFactory(consumerFactory());
        return factory;
    }
}
```

KafkaProucerConfig.java

```
@Configuration
public class KafkaProducerConfig {

    @Value(value = "${spring.kafka.properties.bootstrap.servers}")
    private String bootstrapAddress;

    @Bean
    public ProducerFactory<String, String> producerFactory() {
        final Map<String, Object> configProps = new HashMap<>();
        configProps.put(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, bootstrapAddress);
        configProps.put(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class);
        configProps.put(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class);

        configProps.put(
                SslConfigs.SSL_KEYSTORE_LOCATION_CONFIG,
                "path\\to\\producer.keystore.jks");
        configProps.put(SslConfigs.SSL_KEYSTORE_PASSWORD_CONFIG, "password");
        configProps.put(SslConfigs.SSL_KEY_PASSWORD_CONFIG, "password");
        configProps.put(
                SslConfigs.SSL_TRUSTSTORE_LOCATION_CONFIG,
                "path\\to\\truststore.jks");
        configProps.put(SslConfigs.SSL_TRUSTSTORE_PASSWORD_CONFIG, "password");

        return new DefaultKafkaProducerFactory<>(configProps);
    }

    @Bean
    public KafkaTemplate<String, String> kafkaTemplate() {
        return new KafkaTemplate<>(producerFactory());
    }
}
```

My application.properties does contain

```
spring.kafka.properties.bootstrap.servers=${KAFKA_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS}
```

which is set in a SpringBootTest via

```
System.setProperty("KAFKA_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS", "localhost:9093");
```

All certificates are signed with the root CA.
My docker container starts just fine, but then, when I try to start my Springboot Test, which tries to connect to the broker I get those errors:

```
16:16:48.786 [kafka-admin-client-thread | adminclient-1] INFO  o.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient:341 - [AdminClient clientId=adminclient-1] Cancelled in-flight API_VERSIONS request with correlation id 26 due to node -1 being disconnected (elapsed time since creation: 2ms, elapsed time since send: 2ms, request timeout: 3600000ms)
16:16:48.893 [kafka-admin-client-thread | adminclient-1] INFO  o.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient:935 - [AdminClient clientId=adminclient-1] Node -1 disconnected.

16:17:42.434 [org.springframework.kafka.KafkaListenerEndpointContainer#0-0-C-1] INFO  o.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient:935 - [Consumer clientId=consumer-sales.quotation.quotation.receiver-1, groupId=sales.quotation.quotation.receiver] Node -1 disconnected.
16:17:42.434 [kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-1] INFO  o.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient:341 - [Producer clientId=producer-1] Cancelled in-flight API_VERSIONS request with correlation id 150 due to node -1 being disconnected (elapsed time since creation: 1ms, elapsed time since send: 1ms, request timeout: 30000ms)
16:17:42.434 [org.springframework.kafka.KafkaListenerEndpointContainer#0-0-C-1] INFO  o.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient:341 - [Consumer clientId=consumer-sales.quotation.quotation.receiver-1, groupId=sales.quotation.quotation.receiver] Cancelled in-flight API_VERSIONS request with correlation id 153 due to node -1 being disconnected (elapsed time since creation: 2ms, elapsed time since send: 2ms, request timeout: 30000ms)
16:17:42.434 [kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-1] WARN  o.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient:1063 - [Producer clientId=producer-1] Bootstrap broker localhost:9093 (id: -1 rack: null) disconnected
16:17:42.434 [org.springframework.kafka.KafkaListenerEndpointContainer#0-0-C-1] WARN  o.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient:1063 - [Consumer clientId=consumer-sales.quotation.quotation.receiver-1, groupId=sales.quotation.quotation.receiver] Bootstrap broker localhost:9093 (id: -1 rack: null) disconnected
16:17:42.542 [kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-1] INFO  o.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient:935 - [Producer clientId=producer-1] Node -1 disconnected.
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1):

I think you are maybe missing this important parameter in application configuration in order to enable SSL connection:

```
spring:
  kafka:
    security:
      protocol: "SSL"
```